# rails array mixing text and integer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

With

```ruby
def change
  create_table :something do |t|
    t.text :keyword, array: true, default: []
  end
end
```

I want to make a data that is like [["a", **1**],["b", **5**]].

it worked unexpectedly. like,

> e.keyword = [["a", 1],["b",2]] => [["a", 1], ["b", 2]].

Is this the right way to implement it in rails4?

Comment: _I think this makes [["a", "1"],["b", "5"]] for example._  Could you explain? Are you sure ? Are you test?

Comment: all of the data inside :keyword will be text right?

Comment: Using rails c, it worked unexpectedly. like, > e.keyword = [["a", 1],["b",2]]
 => [["a", 1], ["b", 2]]  But I am wondering if this is the way.

Comment: Why you do not want to check?

Comment: This can help http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Serialization/ClassMethods.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing much about your use case and application, I would recommend that you think about whether or not it would make sense to create a new model for whatever data you want to store within the array.

The reason for this is that it would allow you to use a `has_many` relationship between `something` and the array, and you could easily create and test the arrays in isolation.

```
class MyArray < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :text,   presence: true
  validates :number, presence: true, numericality: { only_integer: true }
  belongs_to :something
end
```

You can change the validations of course to what you need.

```
class Something < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :my_arrays
end
```

And again, extend the class to match what you need.

The migration would look like this:

```
def change
  create_table :my_arrays do |t|
    t.text       :text
    t.integer    :number
    t.belongs_to :something
  end
end
```

Using a separate class for the array allows you to use all the nice features of Rails to deal with the association between `something` and the array, and it makes it easier to work with the data later on (`something.my_arrays.first.text` instead of `something.text[0][0]`). And if you need it, you can use validations to control what content you put into the array.

Think about it.